# Expose and use privileged method in object after initialization

Tags: javascript, function, oop

I have two object constructor functions "classes". The first runs an async operation and executes a callback when data is ready. Within the callback I initialize the second function.

I want to be able to expose certain properties via a wrapper function. These properties will be polled every so often as required. I'm not certain that by the time these properties are queried, the second object would have been initialized.

```
var Wrapper = function(){
   //This may take a while to finish
   var foo = new Foo(function(err,data){
      bar = new Bar(data);
   });

   //this can be queried every few 100ms
   this.getProp(){
       return this.bar.getProp();
   }
}

var w = new Wrapper();
w.getProp(); //Cannot read property 'getProp' of undefined
```

What is the best way to expose such data?

Comment: Initial the object using the ```new``` keyword.

Comment: That doesnt seem to be the problem. The problem is that at the time a new Wrapper is created, bar has yet to be initialized.

Comment: When is the Foo class calling the provided callback function?

Comment: In the code, the function provided to Foo is never called and is probably called by Foo sometimes but not sure when that is happening. Also the bar will can be undefined due to the asynchronous nature of the code. What exactly would you want to happen when that is the case? Would you want to wait for the data? If yes, the bar property must be a promise we can wait for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say this is a best approach. It's more of a get-your-pseudocode-working example.

```js
function Foo(cb) {
  // simulate initialization delay
  setTimeout(() => cb(null, {
    wookies: 12
  }), 3000);
}

function Bar(data) {
  this.data = data;
}

function Wrapper() {
  const setBar = (err, data) => this.bar = new Bar(data);
  //This may take a while to finish
  new Foo(setBar);

  //this can be queried every few 100ms
  this.getProp = function() {
    if (!this.bar) {
      // not ready yet
      console.log('still awaiting initialization');
      return;
    }
    return this.bar.data;
  }
}

const w = new Wrapper();

function go() {
  const x = w.getProp();
  if (!x) {
    setTimeout(go, 100);
  } else {
    console.log(x);
  }
}

go();
```